# New Relic - Query that shows the relationship between APIs and memory consumption in a period

Tags: newrelic

does anyone know any query that shows the relationship between APIs and memory consumption in a period?

Example between 2022-10-17 10:00:00 AM and 2022-10-17 11:00:00 AM

```
 API  | Memory Consumption
__________________________
   X  |  1.5 GB
   Y  |  1 GB
   T  |  0.5 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

A process uses memory. An api can be represented by >1 processes. In the garbage collected world, a process may consume and then release memory as collection cycles are async with api usage. A tool like the infrastructure agent is best placed to monitor the usage of memory for a process, but different languages have different methods of starting Apis so some knowledge of the process/language used for an api may be required.